# is this a good way to add a event to a custom jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jquery plugin.

Is it ok to write/add the event 'click' like this below, as the html that I want to add the event to is being dynamically injected

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


 /* To be moved to own custom js plugin file ------------------------------------------- */

        (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {



                //add events
                $('body').on('click', '.injectedSpan', function () {
                    //alert($(this).html());
                    $(this).remove();

                });


                //custom plugin
                $.fn.addMySpan = function () {


                    return this.each(function () {

                        $(this).append('<span style="cursor:pointer" class="injectedSpan"> added</span>');

                    });

                };

            });

        }(jQuery));

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/



        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#One,#Two,#Three').addMySpan();




        });



    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" >
        <div>




            <div id="One">test1</div>

            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <div id="Two">test2</div>

            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <div id="Three">test3</div>


        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's ok, but not the only way to do it, and might not be the best.

Comment: can you point me in the write direction please - the stuff Im seeing online  in my searches is to complex - thanks

Comment: there's not enough information here for me to point you in any particular direction. Why does this event need to be outside of the plugin at all? couldn't you bind the event and event handler inside the plugin?

Comment: because I thought that if if bind it as a delegate then  its only added once and used as a pointer. but if I do it in the plugin per object then if there are multiple then to many event will get added.

Comment: True, however it's also inefficient to delegate events to the body, because now EVERY click on the webpage will have to be processed to see if it matches that selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it :

```
$.fn.addMySpan = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $el = $('<span>', {style : 'cursor:pointer', class : 'injectedSpan', text : 'added'})
        $el.click(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        })
        $(this).append($el);
    });
};
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tgZZq/

It is a personnal preference, but I prefer it like that. Try avoiding delegated event, bind directly on the element. It is clearer, cleaner and faster.

Comment: is off necessary here as the click was not addd it a on()? thanks

Comment: Can be simplified to: http://jsfiddle.net/tgZZq/2/ or even http://jsfiddle.net/tgZZq/3/

Comment: off is not necessary because `.remove()` unbinds the events, not because it wasn't added by `.on()`

Comment: @KevinB Learned something today, didn't know `.remove()` was removing events aswell, thank.